# How to define custom routes in theme?

Tags: php, drupal, routes, drupal-8

I'm a Drupal 7 regular user, but this is the first time I use Drupal 8.

I'm trying to define custom routes in my theme, but it seems my routing file is not taken into account. Here's my theme relevant files:

```
foo/
  src/
    Controller/
      TestController.php
  templates/
    test/
      list.html.twig
  foo.routing.yml
```

With `foo.routing.yml`:

```
foo.test:
  path: '/test-url'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\foo\Controller\TestController::list'
    _title: 'D8 routing test page'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

And `TestController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\foo\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class TestController extends ControllerBase
{

    public function list() {
        return array(
            '#theme' => 'test/list.html.twig',
            '#bar'   => 'Variable transmission test'
        );
    }

}
```

The current result when I call `/test-url` is not my template, but the standard node page, with all fields displayed.
Am I missing something to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use theme name, not the template path in your render array:

```
public function list() {
    return array(
        '#theme' => 'list',
        '#bar'   => 'Variable transmission test'
    );
}
```

Also, by default, Drupal doesn't have 'list' theme, so you need to define it to (in your foo.theme file):

```
function foo_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'list' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'bar' => NULL
      )
    )
  );
```

UPD: @zessx addition: route declaration can be implemented in a module, not in a theme.

Comment: This was a part of my problem. The otherpart was that you cannot define routes in a theme. Only in a module.